# Three JS canvas not resizing to mobile device window width

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js

I am learning how to make 3D animations using Three JS and I am trying to make one with multiples spinning cubes. The issue is that the whole canvas does not resize when zooming in or out or when the page is viewed on mobile devices, it seems that the camera crops the scene, because the objects keep the same size and only part of the animation shows up. I want to make the whole canvas to have its width equal to the browser window width, and the height with its proportional dimension in any screen width and if the user tries to zoom in or out. Can someone help please? Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        canvas { 
            width: inherit !important;
            height: inherit !important;
            margin: 0 auto; 
            min-width: 300px;
            min-height: 100px;
            max-height: 485px;
            max-width: 900px;
        }
        #anim{
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 900px !important;
            width: 100%;

            background-color: grey;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
    <div id="anim">
    </div>
    <script>

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 8, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
        var div = document.getElementById("anim");

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        div.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
        document.body.appendChild( div );
        var cubes =[];
        for ( i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.3, 0.3, 0.3 ); 
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00, wireframe:true } );
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            if(i<5){
                cube.position.set(-1+(i/2),-0.4,0);
            }else{
                cube.position.set(-3.5+(i/2),0.4,0);
            }


            cubes[i] = cube;
            scene.add(cubes[i]);
        }
        camera.position.z=10;
        function render() {

            for ( var i = 0 ; i < scene.children.length; i ++ ) {

                var object = scene.children[ i ];

                object.rotation.x += 0.01;
                object.rotation.y += 0.1;


            }


            requestAnimationFrame( render );
            renderer.render(scene, camera);

        };

        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        function onWindowResize() { 
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth,  window.innerHeight);

        }
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you clarify the problem? how exactly is it you want the program to behave when "zooming"? And by zooming, i suspect you mean translating the camera closer the the objects?

Comment: Ah, reread the question now and i think i understand. when zooming (changing the angle of view, 20 in your example), you also want the canvas to change in size respectively?

Comment: I edited my question. Yes that is what I want it to do.

Comment: where is your zoom action defined?

Comment: At the end of my js, onWindowResize()

Comment: Remove the `renderer.setSize()` call from the `render()` function and move it under your `renderer` definition. You don't need to keep setting the `renderer` size continuously. Also remove the `cubes` from your `render()` function definition and call.

Comment: I did what you suggested. But it still looks "cropped". The objects keep their size when I test on FF Responsive design mode, using a mobile screen size. The canvas width doesn't change to the screen size value.

Comment: is `onWindowResize()` being called? and is `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` being updated?

Comment: only when using a computer screen, with smaller devices it seems to crop. yes, the dimensions seem to update, but like in my previous statement.

Answer (score 0):

As I used this code for my canvas to be responsive to all of the size of window you can check my code below.

```js
function render() {
    if (resize(renderer)) {
        camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function resize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
        renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
}


window.addEventListener( 'resize', function() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight )
})
```